# Table Space-HTML in Outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook

I am currently in the process of creating the newsletter for my company this quarter. I am by no means an HTML expert and this is not my main duty in my position.

The issue is that when i send the email as a test through our email marketing platfor (Switpage E Marketing), it looks fine in my inbox. However, when i send it to my boss's email, the table spacing looks terrible, the middle spacing between the top two spaces is all stretched out, and the whole newsletter table expands, making it unorganized and hideous.

[I have attached the newsletter here](https://www.swiftpage4.com/speasapage.aspx?X=2W17YMD5M36CPM0K00Y9WW)

Thanks for your help,

Mike

Comment: I have the same problem when I use tables to possition something, I solved it by removing the tables. But not shure what caused this problem.

Comment: Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: What is the difference between your inbox and your boss's? What email clients are you using? POP, IMAP, Exchange, Exchange versions, webmail, which webmail, which browsers to view the webmail, which OS's do the browsers run on, what kind of firewalls, virus checkers, adblockers are installed, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few common culprits for vertical(?) spacing in email.

Firstly, set all images to `display:block;`. This is needed for Outlook to stop adding spaces below each image.

Also add this to your style tag `table, td {border-collapse: collapse;}`

Are you forwarding your email to your boss after you receive it, or is he getting it first hand? Email forwarded from Outlook will create gaps as Outlook inserts a lot of MS Word junk.

On a side note, you don't need `<tbody>` or `<center>` tags. Use `align="center"` instead for that.

Comment: There is "Outlook" in the question title, but I agree that is not nearly enough info to work with.

Comment: Thank you for the input. It is going straight to his email through the software we use to send email blasts.

Comment: This is what the outcome of the email looks like-I want everything to be tight and together,instead the table expands and there is bizzare white space on the right side http://www.swiftpage4.com/Orchard.Mbrazitis/ImageLibrary/error.jpg

Comment: One of your td tags is set as 'th', try fixing that first. Also, remove the center tags and tbody tags. If that doesn't work, repost the updated code. @user2820434